# C++ to conver hours, minutes, seconds to seconds

Tags: c++

> Write a program that asks the user to enter a time duration in hours, minutes, and seconds and then displays the time in terms of seconds in decimal format. There are 60 minutes in an hour, and there are 60 seconds in a minute. Represent these number of minutes in an hours and number of seconds in a minute as constant in your program. You should use a separate variable for each input value.
>
> Please make sure that minutes and seconds are less than or equal to 59. If the users enter this more than 59 or negative it should be asking him to re-enter the information.

Sorry about this question. I am a beginner in C++, trying to read some books and answer the questions on my own, but I am stuck on this question. I dont think I'm going anywhere here.

[image: A screenshot of code]

Comment: This sounds like an assignment, the first paragraph especially looks like it was copy/pasted from the assignment brief. Unfortunately for you, this is not a homework website. Best of luck learning c+.

Comment: I would suggest when asking questions like this on Stack Overflow that you actually show the work that you have done so far, otherwise, you will have people telling you that this is not a homework site! I hope you don't mind, but I edited your question to include the screenshot of your work. Next time, try and put the source code in as text. This will allow people to copy and paste the code into an IDE, and play with the code a little :)

Comment: There is not a single question mark in the entire "question"!!!!!

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Please be more specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "Enter hours, minutes and seconds." << endl;
    cout << "hours:";
    cin >> hour;
    if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
    {
        cout << "Error: hours should be in between [0..23]" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    cout << "minutes:";
    cin >> min;
    if (min < 0 || min > 59)
    {
        cout << "Error: minutes should be in between [0..59]" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    cout << "seconds:";
    cin >> sec;
    if (sec < 0 || sec > 59)
    {
        cout << "Error: seconds should be in between [0..59]" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    // now all the data should be verified already
    break;
}

cout << "Total seconds: " << (sec + min*60 + hour*60*60) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what about a loop and break it when the value is valid.